# How to configure a router behind a router

Tags: networking, router, subnet

I'm new to networking and I'm working on setting up a home computer lab for myself so I can practice hands-on as I learn. I have an Xfinity home WiFi router that's connected to my ISP. I have connected another WiFI router to the Xfinity router (this one is NetGear), by inserting one end of an ethernet cable into the port labeled "Internet" on the NetGear router and the other end into a port labeled "Ethernet" on the Xfinity router. When I connect to the NetGear router's WiFi on my laptop and go to http://10.0.0.1, I see the configuration webpage for the Xfinity router. What IP address do I go to to see the configuration page for the NetGear router?

Answer (score 1):

1). Reset the NetGear Router to factory default.
2). Connect the NetGear Router to your computer using Ethernet cable.
3). See the default IP address, username and password which are described below the router.
4). Open your favorite browser, go to the IP address mentioned above in step 3.
5). Enter username and password mentioned in step 3.
6). Search for the router's IP address and change it to

```
IP Address : 10.0.0.2
Subnet Mask : 255.0.0.0
Default Gateway : 10.0.0.1
```

7). Restart the router and reseat the cables as you have done and test it out.

Please let me know if my answer is OK or not :)

Answer (score 1):

The default internal IP address of the Netgear router is most likely `192.168.0.1`. If your laptop is running Windows , you can verify by opening up a command prompt (`Windows Key + R`, type `cmd`, hit `Enter` or click `OK`), typing `ipconfig` in the command prompt, and then hitting `Enter`. Look for the line with `Default Gateway` - that IP address is the IP address for the Netgear router.